# Less options after using nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

After installing Nvidia proprietary drivers from software center, I could access to nvidia x server options which looked like this:

[Previous Xserver Configuration options (source: Google images)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbgEL.png)

Now it looks like this

[Current Xserver configuration options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ttXc.png)

How do I get the old options back?

There are no modifications done on grub launch parameters (all I have is quiet splash)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: already disabled

Comment: Well `nvidia` proprietary driver is not in use for some reason. It's hard to guess what happened between "before" and "now".

Comment: Yeah, you're right. lsmod | grep nvidia returns nothing. I'll reinstall ubuntu if there are no fix for this issue.

Comment: Maybe some kernel update broke it.

Answer (score 0):

As [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/users/167850/pilot6) said

> Maybe some kernel update broke it.

I had installed 4.19 and 5 versions because I couldn't get my touchpad working (It still did not work)
It seems it broke nvidia driver too. after purging the kernel upgrades and reverting back to 4.15, the options came back.